# to read file and then to convert it to lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

Looking for codes in prolog to convert a file.txt to lists as following:

```
3  3
10 80 30
40 50 20 10
2  3  5  6
6  2  6  9
4  6  8  1

List1=[3,3]
List2=[10,80,30]
List3=[40,50,20,10]
Cost=[[2,3,5,6],[6,2,6,9],[4,6,8,1]]
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, you have to show what you've tried so far and why it doesn't work.   At that point, people here will be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Complete code:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics), except([eos/2])).

lists(Input_path) :-
    DCG = read_lists(Lists),
    phrase_from_file(DCG,Input_path), !,
    Lists = [List1,List2,List3,List4,List5,List6],
    format('List1=~w~n',[List1]),
    format('List2=~w~n',[List2]),
    format('List3=~w~n',[List3]),
    format('Cost=[~w,~w,~w]~n',[List4,List5,List6]).

eos([], []).

read_lists([]) --> call(eos).
read_lists([List|Lists]) -->
    read_list(List),
    (
        "\n"
    |
        []
    ),
    read_lists(Lists).
read_lists([]) --> [].

read_list([Item|Items]) -->
    number(Item),
    whites,
    read_list(Items).
read_list([]) --> [].
```

Example run:

```
?- lists("C:/data.txt").
List1=[3,3]
List2=[10,80,30]
List3=[40,50,20,1]
Cost=[[2,3,5,6],[6,2,6,9],[4,6,8,1]]
true.
```

---

Explanation of code

While parsing of list can be done with recursive code and keeping and passing the [state](https://www.metalevel.at/tist/) variables manually, doing it with Definitive Clause Grammars ([DCG](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg)) is easier.

When doing DCG there are prewritten libraries of predicates. The most popular library for DCGs when using SWI-Prolog is [DCG/basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl).

This line of code brings in the library. However eos/2 causes an error so I exclude it and add it in the code manually.

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics), except([eos/2])).
```

DCG are clauses that hide two state variables that can be seen by using [listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1).

All of the code that uses `-->` instead of `:-` are DCG.

A common way to use DCGs is with [phrase/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase/2) but reading data from a file and then using phrase is so common there is a better predicate to use [phrase_from_file/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase_from_file/2).

The two clauses in the DCG from the library are `number//1` and `whites//0`.

`eos` is for end_of_steam and is used in the base case for `read_lists//1`

[format/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) is used to write out the result.

The rest is standard simple Prolog.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This code can be used to generate a 2D list of 3*3. Could you modify the code ,so that it can generate a 2D list of n*n? At the same time, I have a piece of code, can you help me debug it ?

Comment: I appreciate you very mich

Comment: I appreciate you very much! I have posted it as new problem. I look for your helpping